# Convert time scalar field to velocity vector field

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient, vector-fields

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to create *vector* velocity field from some raster containing spatial distribution of *scalar* variable (timestamp of some mass-media event in my case).

Here is my GeoTIFF overlapped with isochrones drown from the six-hours interval. Cold colors correspond to zones where some event happened earlier. Warm colors match to the areas where that event occurred later:

[image]

I would like to convert that GeoTIFF image to format quite common for fluid dynamics and hydro-meteorology: a [quiver plot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html). I suggest that vectors should represent the speed of information spatial dissemination.

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import *
import numpy
import pylab

dataset = gdal.Open("raster.tif", GA_ReadOnly)
_ar = dataset.ReadAsArray()

#Making the dataset little bit sparser...
nth=4
ar = _ar[::nth, ::nth]
X = numpy.arange(0, _ar.shape[0], nth)
Y = numpy.arange(0, _ar.shape[0], nth)
x, y = numpy.gradient(ar)

pylab.quiver(X, Y, x, y)
pylab.savefig("out.png")
```

The resulting vector field:
[image]

I guess I'm doing something wrong in the code above cause result is confusing. You can see that in fact I'm getting the *gradients of timestamp*, whereas I really need the *gradients of velocity*. The warmer zones are surrounded by large arrows corresponding to long periods of information dissemination, **BUT** I need the opposite effect:

longer time lag <-> low information distribution speed <-> warmer color <->  shorter arrows

shorter time lag <-> high information distribution speed <-> colder color <->   longer arrows

I would appreciate to get possible solutions in Python or R.

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly how your result is "wrong"?  What would the *right* result look like and what would it represent?

Comment: @whuber, I think I get _time_ gradients whereas I really need _velocity_ gradients.